# Angular 5 commands.reduce is not a function in router.navigate

Tags: angular

I'm sending a string as a link to my router, eg "/blog/pages/3"

However I'm getting the error "commands.reduce is not a function"

The navigate does work though, just the error shows up in the console

```
goToPage(link) {
  this.router.navigate(link);
}
```

Comment: try passing your Id in second argument, like this `this.router.navigate(['/pageURL', id]);}`

Comment: My ID is not '3' in this case, it's the whole string.  My link variable is '/blog/pages/3'

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: but, your route have ID parameter you cant redirect directly using whole string, you need to pass ID.

Comment: Try `navigateByUrl` method. `navigate` expects a command array and you are passing a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use router.navigateByUrl and router.navigate in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025334/how-to-use-router-navigatebyurl-and-router-navigate-in-angular)

Comment: navigateByUrl did it thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The function should be written like this. Use square brackets in the parameter:

```
goToPage(link) {
  this.router.navigate([link]);
}
```