# navigateByUrl from parent to child route not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I would navigate to a sub component in my app.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.rightsService.pathToRedirectTo).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

It's working when I pass `/mainRoute`
Routing :

`{ path: 'mainRoute', loadChildren: () => import('./xxx/xxxx').then(m => m.xxxModule) },`

But not redirecting ( data = false ) when I pass `/mainRoute/subRoute/1`

Here's how my routing be like:

`{ path: 'subRoute/:id', canActivate: [ViewGuard], component: ViewComponent },`

I don't know why the second case is not working ?

Here's my parent routing

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'mainRoute', loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.mainModule) },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }];
```

Then inside mainModule

I have routing:

```
{ path: 'subRoute/:id', canActivate: [ViewGuard], component: ViewComponent },
{ path: 'subroute/:id/childRoute/:sId', canActivate: [SViewGuard], component: SiewComponent }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check please what the return your `ViewGuard` when you try to redirect to `/mainRoute/subRoute/1`, seems that route guard can return `false` and it could be a reason of this problem, also in case that you use any interceptors for this route or for some parent components, check what the value that interceptors return too.

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. I have deleted the guard to be sure that the error don't came from here. now the `navigateByUrl`  returns `true` but not redirecting it to the  route passed in params.

Comment: One more idea appeared, maybe path `/mainRoute/subRoute/1` doesn't absolute in app. Are there any other parent components with routes? Also you could check, to be definetly sure that something wrong with path, just try to use this route with other method `this.router.navigate(["/mainRoute/subRoute/1"])`, if it won't redirect, i recommend check parent module where you discribed all routes

Comment: Yes I do have parent routing if I have well understood your question, I have added my routing logic to my question.