# how to change the url without destroying the component angular5

Tags: angular, typescript

Just a little new to Angular2 world, however it was preety simpler in angular 1 by specifying {reload: false} but not able to find a similar solution in Angular 2 where I can avoid reloading the component while changing the query param in my route.

I have html template, where I am changing the query parameter on click of a button.

I have the method updateRoute({type: 'app_dependency'}) which gets called on click of the button:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`ngOnInit  - is called. `);
  }
  public updateRoute(urlObject){
    let queryParams = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
    let updatedQuery = clone(queryParams);
    this.activeTab = updatedQuery.type || 'app_dependency';
    forEach(urlObject, (value, key) => {
      updatedQuery[key] = value;
    });
    //this.location.search({type: 'app_dependency'})
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: queryParams
    });
  }
```

But every time this function gets called, it destroys the component and calls ngOnInit().

Is it possible to just change the url query (I am not changing the route but just changing the query) without reloading my component? If yes, can anyone please help me or suggest me a better approach.

Comment: Be aware that `activatedRoute.snapshot` should only be used if the component **never** gets reused ([Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#snapshot-the-no-observable-alternative)), what I think you're trying to achieve.

Comment: do u suggest ot have any example where i can reuse the component @Emaro

Comment: have you tried ``navigate( [] , { skipLocationChange: true }):``  ?

Comment: yes, i tried just now... but still doesnt seems to be working

Comment: If you just left there 4 lines in this `updateRoute` method: `this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: this.activatedRoute.queryParams.snapshot
    });` does it still destroy the component? I'd try to figure out if setting `activeTab` or mutating this `updatedQuery` does not somehow cause your component to be reloaded.

Comment: so I tried to just have following lines (to change the url query), but still see component getting distroyed and ngOnInit being called.. I am on angular5
https://pastebin.com/raw/eJZSHShV

Comment: Please see the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdhbat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts. It just does not reload the component. My guess is you might display the component on i.e. some ngIf, the condition might be temporarily changed and it causes the component to re-render. Anyway, numerous potential reasons.

Comment: @undefined did you solve your problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem and the issue in my case was that in a particular scenario (long story) I had to apply a modified route configuration through [`Router.resetConfig()`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetconfig) on `NavigationEnd`. Because of that reset, the lazy loaded modules were reinitialized upon every query parameter update, which of course triggered `ngOnInit()` each time. More thoughtfully using `resetConfig()` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here:
It will prevent the component from being destroyed.

```
constructor(
        private router: Router
      ) {
        this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
          return true;
        };
      }
```