# Angular: How to update queryParams without changing route on a template

Tags: angular

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698032/angular-how-to-update-queryparams-without-changing-route) but it is not referred to the template.

What I want is to create a link that simply adds or modifies a queryParamenters in the currently -unkwown- route.

```
<a [routerLink]="[¿¿¿???]" [queryParams]="{ pageIndex: 3 }"
 {{ 3 }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems it's as easy as:

```
<a [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="{ pageIndex: 3 }"
 {{ 3 }}
</a>
```